# Jquery variable inside hover not working

Tags: jquery

Hey there, working on the code and kind of got it working.
Now pleeaseee tell me what's wrong.
On hover .photo i make a variable performer with the rel value of a link inside .photo

And i want to use this variable when the mouse leaves.
It does now work, any ideas?

```
$(".photo").hoverIntent(function() {

      var performer = $(".photo").attr("rel");

      $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
    }, function() {
      $(this).html(''+performer+'');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second anonymous function you created cannot see the performer var, it is not in the scope chain.  You must put it outside like this:

```
$('.photo').each(function() { // All of the .photo divs....
    var performer = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).hoverIntent(function() {
        // The second function can't see in here
        $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
    }, function() {
        $(this).html(''+performer+'');
    });
});
```

If you don't know why, i would suggest learning more about closures in javascript.

---

### Edit

Sorry, didn't know there were duplicates...

Use each to iterate through each and create a variable for every .photo, then that varaible can be referenced by the anonymous functions created.

---

### Edit

Also i don't see why you didn't just take your original code and do this:

```
$(this).hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="250" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="250" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('' + $(this).attr("rel") + '');
});
```

Comment: Yes but now it says "undefined" when i hover out of the .photo

I have 10 .photo divs

Comment: Let me explain better... the each method , i'm pretty sure it won't working.

I have 10 .photo divs with 10 different images.

When i hover on any one, it plays the flash. When i hover out, I want the image coresponding to that .photo div to be shown

Answer (score 0):

Make performer a global variable by initiating it outside of the first function like so:

```
var performer = 1;
$(".photo").hoverIntent(function() {

      performer = $(".photo").attr("rel");

      $(this).html('stuff....');
    }, function() {
      $(this).html(''+performer+'');
    });
```